# Update multiple DOM elements by making only one call to ActionResult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to update multiple DOM elements (in this case divs) when I make a certain call in my MVC3 application. All of my Action results are in separate functions all with their own view models:

```
         public ActionResult Action3(ViewModel3 model)
    {
        return PartialView("_DomElement3", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Action2(ViewModel2 model)
    {
        return PartialView("_DomElement2", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Action1(ViewModel1 model)
    {
        return PartialView("_DomElement1", model);
    }
```

Here's what all three razor partial views look like (just with different models):

```
      @model ViewModel1
      <div id='domElement1'>@Model.values1</div>
```

I did it this way because they were being called on demand and I thought nothing else would trigger them. But I ran across a scenario where I will have to update all three of my div elements after a certain criteria is met. I'm currently doing it this way and I don't like it one bit:

```
           var values_1 = {'values1':'one'};
           $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action1")',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: values_1,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#domElement1').html(data);
           var values_2 = {'values2':'two'};
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Action2")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: values_2,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#domElement2').html(data);
           var values_3 = {'values3':'three'};
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("Action3")',
                                                dataType: 'json',
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                contentType: 'application/json;                         charset=utf-8',
                                                data: values_3,
                                                success: function (data) {
                                                    $('#domElement3').html(data);

                                                }
                                            });

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

As you can see, I'm making calls to the server one at a time. Does anyone know a better way to update my elements with only one call to the server?

Comment: Create a ViewModel with all three of your models and return that as needed.

Comment: @Jose - I was kinda thinking along those lines. I'm still searching for another solution if possible. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to build a sample app to test it, but one possibility is to have a method that returns JSON. This response could return an array of partial results:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeMethodName()
{
    /* get your data */

    var results = new List<ActionResult>();

    foreach(var model in YourCollection)
    {
        results.Add(new PartialResult("viewname", mode));
    }

    return Json(results.ToArray());
}
```

This is pretty much pseudo code, but should get the point across.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I know where you're going with this and I like it. I can call all 3 of my action methods, combine the results into a JSON string, return that to the browser and parse the string to the different dom elements. Not a bad idea. Thank you very much